# Proper steps to take when a rebase needs merging

Tags: git, rebase

I pulled a remote repository's master branch and made a new branch.  I modified a few files,  committed them, and pushed to the new branch on the remote server.  I did this several times over the next day.

Then, I checked out the master branch and did a `git pull`.  I then checked out my new branch, and ran `git rebase master`.  This is where it gets a little hazy, and my apologies upfront if I don't explain very well what happened next, as I'm going on memory.

My rebase had some conflicts in a couple of files.  I was told to fix the conflicts, then call `git rebase --continue.`

I generally diff and merge using a 3rd party tool (Araxis) but in this case the git prompt remained where it was, as though it was waiting for me to edit the conflicts *right then* and get back to it.  So, I opened my text editor and removed the appropriate '<<<<' and '-----' bits we've all seen when dealing with conflicts, and saved the files the way I wanted them to look.

From the waiting prompt I then typed `git rebase --continue` and was promptly told to add the files first, then call rebase.  So I ran `git add *` and then `git rebase --continue` and the actions completed.  I was then told I should consider pushing, as origin/new branch was a few commits behind.  So I ran `git push`.

Then I figured I should play it safe and make sure everything was ok, so I called `git checkout master`, called `git pull`, then checked out the new branch and called `git pull` followed by `git rebase master` and the same files were conflicting again, and it felt like I had just completed a circle.

My questions are: what would be a more appropriate series of steps to have taken to keep things smooth when the rebase had conflicts, and does anyone know how the steps that I did take led to the circle I (admittedly, not very well) described above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and called `git pull` followed by `git rebase master`

That is the part where it went wrong.
You don't have to pull your remote branch again, adding a commit representing then changes from `origin`, which, once rebased (again) on `master`, would generate the same conflicts.

I usually do a (since I don't work on `master`, but only on `mybranch`):

```
git checkout mybranch

# Let's not modify any local file
git fetch

# reset my local master branch to the one I just fetched
git branch -f master origin/master

git rebase master
# resolve conflicts
# git add, git rebase --continue
git push
```

Comment: Thank you.  Would it be possible to describe just a bit more the part about resetting your local master branch?  I've never done that before.

Comment: @larryq it is very easy and instantaneous: you just move the pointer '`master`' to '`origin/master`', which is what '`git branch -f`' does. When you are working on your own branch and monitoring an upstream repo, you want your local `master` to reflect what `origin/master` looks like.